# Storing data from WMS Server locally for ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, wms, software-recommendations, cache

I am new to GIS, and I am digitizing a map that is being provided from a WMS Server. As a result, zooming in and zooming out of the map takes loads of time due to a slow Internet connection.

I was wondering if anyone knew of any tools to download the entire file from the WMS Server to local memory, so that I do not need a fast Internet connection in order to work?

I seek links to any such tools, and steps on how to use it for this purpose.

Comment: Wait a minute. You're digitizing the all features being served by a web mapping service? Is that permitted? Why not just obtain the data from the provider?

Answer (score 1):

I use MapProxy to achieve this. It's an open source proxy for geospatial data. It can be found on https://mapproxy.org/.

The tutorials on how to use MapProxy can be found on https://mapproxy.org/docs/latest/.